# Function with side effects

Tags: c, function

I am beginner in C and trying to implement a function that returns the value but also changes the array as the side effect via pointer. I am aware that I should free up all the memory at the end but that is out of the topic here.

My compiler says that there is no place left on device and signals "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". Does this have something to do with pointers or have I made an error in function itself?

```
int load(int *a) {
    int i,n;
    printf("Input the number of elements ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf("Input the elements ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
        scanf("%d ",a+i);
    return n;
}

int add(int *a, int n) {
    int sum=0, i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum+=*(a+i);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int *a,n1,z1;
    n1=load(a);
    z1=add(a,n1);
    printf("Sum of the array is %d", z1);
}
```

Comment: "no place left on device" sounds like it is trying to tell you that the disk is full.  Delete some files to free up space.

Comment: I freed up the space but now i am getting random segmentation faults. I input 3 as the number of elements but program doesn't run after i input 3 elements and asks for another one. After inputing another random number program crushes with segmentation fault.

Comment: The `a` in `load` is not the same as `a` in `main`. So changing `a` in `load` does nothing to the `a` in `main`.

Comment: Look up "pass by value"

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you learned to indent subordinate statements, and changed things like `*(a+i)` to `a[i]`.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: And yes, your bug is that the `a` that you allocate with `malloc` in `load` is not being passed back to `main`, so when you call `add` from `main`, you're passing it an undefined pointer.  In fact, the `a` that you pass to `load` from `main` is undefined (and unused in `load`).

Comment: The variable `a` in `main` is not changed since you pass a copy of the pointer to your function `load()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is logical error in your code

```
int *a,n1,z1;
```

In main function variable 'a' is a pointer variable.

It is a local variable and is not assigned to any address.

It points to some random address.(Let us say pointer is pointing to address 0x1000)

```
n1=load(a);
```

Here only value of pointer is passed.

i.e., 0x1000 is passed and is assigned to another local variable 'a' of function load.

```
a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Here malloc returns the dynamically allocated address.

=> value passed as an argument is lost and new value which is allocated dynamically is present in local pointer variable 'a'.

```
scanf("%d ",a+i);
```

All the input elements are assigned at dynamically allocated address, not at address 0x1000

```
z1=add(a,n1);
```

Here again main function pointer variable 'a' which is pointing to some random address is passed as first argument, not the dynamically allocated memory.

Behaviour is **undefined** as we don't know the address to which main function pointer variable 'a' is pointing.